# Tooltip on invisible SVG element

Tags: svg, d3.js, tooltip

I'm drawing a line across multiple data points using d3.svg.line.  I don't want to show anything to represent the individual data points -- just the bare line -- but I'd like to be able to mouse over the inflection points where the line segments meet to see tooltip information about each data point.

I've added a `<g>` element positioned at each datapoint and the `<title>` element works fine for tooltips as long as I have something visible, like `<circle>` as the parent of `<title>`.  But if I use `<title>` directly under `<g>`, it doesn't show anything.  If I set the fill/stroke of `<circle>` to "none", the tooltip no longer appears.

Is there a simple way to get tooltips to appear over specific points without any visible elements being present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw a transparent rect and put the tooltip on that perhaps? fill="transparent"

Comment: That should be fill="none", since fill="transparent" is invalid according to the svg spec.

Comment: As soon as I set fill and stroke to "none" the tooltip stops showing up, at least in Chrome.

Comment: Firefox supports transparent and rgba colours from http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color Hopefully SVG 2 will mandate support of CSS3 colours rather than the CSS 2 specification that SVG 1.1 references.

Comment: If other UAs don't support transparent or rgba colours you could try fill="none" together with pointer-events="visible" or perhaps pointer-events="all".

Comment: I had no idea about the "pointer-events" property.  It worked like a charm.  Thanks so much.